# Download a file with download manager Issue in android

Tags: android, file, android-download-manager

I am downloading a file from specific URL.  The function is working fine with other URL for downloading the file but when I try to download a song from [this](http://pleer.com/browser-extension/files/72338325d4W.mp3) URL then code runs successfully but downloaded song is just 7 kb in size. Actual size of song is more than 12MB. Am I missing something?

Here is my code to download a song.

```
    private void DownloadTask(String downloadUrl){
    Log.e("downloadUrl==>",downloadUrl+"");

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadUrl));
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);

    request.setDescription("Downloading "+downloadingSongName  );
    request.setTitle("Music App");
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);

    if(ExternalStorage.isAvailable()){
        // if sd card is available
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(MusicConstants.FOLDERNAME, downloadingSongName);

        final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);

        showDownloadProgressDialog("Downloading " + downloadingSongName, getActivity());

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                boolean downloading = true;

                while (downloading) {

                    DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    q.setFilterById(downloadId);

                    Cursor cursor = manager.query(q);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                    int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                        downloading = false;
                        dismissDialog();
                    }


                    final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);

                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            try {
                                mProgressBar.setProgress((int) dl_progress);
                                double progressValue=dl_progress;
                                txtDevide.setText(dl_progress+"/100");
                                int percentage=(int) ((progressValue*100)/100);
                                txtpercentage.setText(percentage+"%");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }else{

        showMessage(getActivity(), "No Sd card available.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in the LogCat ?

Comment: No. Nothing. I can see the downloaded file in SD card as well.

Comment: i guess you should set `request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");` and it would be done

Comment: @KaranMer. Thanks for your efforts, I have checked but no success.

Comment: @HiteshKamani can you try using it with internal storage instead of sdcard

Comment: Yes I already tried it. still awaits for success.

Comment: chk this once http://www.sandersdenardi.com/using-the-android-downloadmanager/

Comment: @KaranMer thanks. the code I wrote is working fine with other URLs but it is not working with reference url i provided. I will check your code once again and will tell you if find anything useful. Thanks again buddy.

Comment: ` downloaded song is just 7 kb in size.`. Is it really - a part of- a song? Or a html page? Please look into it. Maybe there is redirection involved.

Comment: no I think it is not a part of song or some html file. it is showing as binary file in Linux OS.