# Can not download file with download manager from server

Tags: android, url, android-download-manager

I am using following code for downloading mp3 files from server in Android.
but when loop executes for first time the following line shows same 7 bytes size. Here is the [file](http://pleer.com/browser-extension/files/54035010xXY.mp3) I tries to download.

```
int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
```

and also following line shows success

```
 if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
         downloading = false;
         dismissDialog();
  }
```

so my downloading stops.actual size of mp3 file is more than 5 MB but I can see only 7 bytes of file in my SD card. Here is my actual [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571393/download-a-file-with-download-manager-issue-in-android). Please help me to find out the possible solution. is there anything wrong with url of mp3 file?